# Is it possible to change the way rails renders a small piece of code

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, video.js

I'm trying to set up [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) and I'm following the guide [here](http://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-setup.html#automatic-setup).

You'll see that for automatic setup the video needs to be initialized like this:

```
<video class="video-js" data-setup='{}'>
```

Which I thought would be fine because in rails I can do this:

```
<%= video_tag @video.filename + '.mp4', :class => 'video-js', 'data-setup' => '{}' %>
```

However, that renders the tag like this:

```
<video class="video-js" data-setup="{}" src="/assets/0019 Trump Android.mp4"></video>
```

That looks fine at first glance except that the data-setup line needs single quotes, not double quotes, or videojs setup won't work. Like this: `data-setup='{}'`

So is there any way to get rails to render that one attribute with single quotes instead of double quotes?

Also, a second thought, why should I have rails render the video tag when I could just write it in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers are just there to make things easier to read syntactically, and easier to program. If you write HTML instead of ERB it performs the same, provided your HTML tags print out everything ERB would have otherwise printed.

In this specialized usecase, I would just write the entire HTML tag surrounded by an ERB `.each` tag. Not sure how you have your controller set up, but under the assumption it was something like `@videos = Videos.all`, it would be something like this:

```
<% @videos.each do |video| %>
  <video class="video-js" data-setup='{}' src=<%=video.file_name%>>
  </video>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`video_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/video_tag) helper does have some use like the `poster` attribute which references an image, so it's needed for that, to include the digest of the image file. However for your use case I don't see any reason to use the helper when it's quite easy to just write the pure html yourself.